# setInterval how to stop it to load different css to work

Tags: javascript

How do you stop an interval heres my code:

function timeres(){

if ((screen.width!=1280) && (screen.height!=1024))
{
 document.write
}

}

setInterval('timeres()',1);

The code works great without the setinterval when i change resolutions i have to refresh the page to make the css take effect but i want it to auto change after a user changes his/her resolution so i thought maybe a setinterval will work

go easy on code im a noob :D

Answer (score 0):

A call to `setInterval` returns a reference to the timeout you have requested. You can cancel this with `clearTimeout`.

```
function timeres() {
    if ((screen.width!=1280) && (screen.height!=1024)) {    
        document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'href='css/style1024.css'  />"); 
    }  
}

var timeoutReference = setInterval('timeres()',1);

clearInterval(timeoutReference);
```

Comment: "var timeoutReference = setInterval(timeres, 1);" is correct as well.

Comment: cram i tried it but no response heres the codefunction timeres() {
    if ((screen.width==1280) && (screen.height==1024)) {    
        document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style2.css'  />"); 
    }  
}

var timeoutReference = setInterval('timeres()',1);

clearTimeout(timeoutReference);

Answer (score 0):

I think that what would help you is to get familiar with events, especially onresize. So you don't need to do a time-delayed check in a loop.

```
window.onresize = function() {
    if ((screen.width!=1280) && (screen.height!=1024)) {    
        document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'href='css/style1024.css'  />");
    }      
};
```

Comment: i tried it but the page just keeps loading i can see it reloading heres the code window.onresize = function() {
    if ((screen.width!=1280) && (screen.height!=1024)) {    
        document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'href='css/style1024.css'  />");
    }      
};

Answer (score 0):

@Jon Cram almost had it, but referenced wrong clear method. [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.clearInterval) is what you want, after you store the result of the `setInterval` to reference. e.g.

```
// declare the interval, and make it a variable for reference
var theInterval = setInterval(foo,1000);

// then to clear it, clear that reference
clearInterval(theInterval);
```

Also, though I know it's kind of shotty/inconsistent, you may want to look in to the [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@media) CSS delcaration for screen-sized based rules.

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  div {
    width: 700px;
  }
}
```